# How to parse XML without Root element using SimpleXML?

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, simple-framework

How to parse below result xml(?) using [SimpleXML](http://simple.sourceforge.net/)?

```
<boolean xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">true</boolean>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved parsing like this:

```
@Root(name="boolean")
public class LogonResult {
    @Text
    boolean _boolean;
}
```